# Lettuce timeout on command level

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, lettuce

I was using lettuce client as a Redis cluster client because it supports Cluster Redis well.

A practical problem I have met is when creating a client or during topological refresh, lettuce will send out "info" command, which usually takes longer than normal get command. Setting a general timeout, for example, 10ms, will cause the client failed to start.

I was wondering if I could set the command timeout based on different command types.

Update:
I have read the source code and found out that I could write my own `TimeoutSource` to set the timeout on command level.

I am posting this question because I have communicated with Mark, the author of Lettuce. We thought it would be helpful to share this issue on the broader community as people could someday meet the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

### TL; DR

It's possible through `TimeoutOptions` and specifically a `TimeoutSource`.

### Details

Lettuce provides since version 5.1 a configuration option to apply either the configured connection timeout, a fixed timeout (not related to the connection timeout) or a per-command timeout.

The entrypoint to configure timeouts is `TimeoutOptions` that can be supplied via `ClientOptions`.

- `TimeoutOptions.enabled(Duration)` uses a fixed timeout.
- `TimeoutOptions.enabled()` applies the connection timeout.
- `TimeoutOptions.builder().timeoutSource(TimeoutSource).build()` uses the provided `TimeoutSource` to determine a timeout on `RedisCommand` level.

If you implement [`TimeoutSource`](https://lettuce.io/core/release/api/io/lettuce/core/TimeoutOptions.TimeoutSource.html) then you can decide on a given `RedisCommand` what timeout to apply.

Answer (score 0):

A small code example implementing `TimeoutSource`. We can pass in a `Map<ProtocolKeyword, Duration>` specifying the timeout for each command.

```java
public class LettucePerCommandTimeoutSource extends TimeoutOptions.TimeoutSource {
  private static final Duration DEFAULT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofMillis(250);
  
  private final Map<ProtocolKeyword, Duration> timeoutByCommand;
  
  LettucePerCommandTimeoutSource(final Map<ProtocolKeyword, Duration> timeoutByCommand) {
    this.timeoutByCommand = timeoutByCommand;
  }
  
  @Override
  public long getTimeout(final RedisCommand<?, ?, ?> command) {
    final var commandType = command.getType();
    if (this.timeoutByCommand.containsKey(commandType)) {
      return this.timeoutByCommand.get(commandType).toMillis();
    }
    return DEFAULT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT.toMillis();
  }
}
```

Then use it for `TimeoutOptions`.

```java
TimeoutOptions timeoutOptions = 
  TimeoutOptions.builder()
    .timeoutSource(new LettucePerCommandTimeoutSource(
        Map.of(
            CommandType.GET, Duration.ofMillis(10),
            CommandType.INFO, Duration.ofMillis(1000))))
    .build();
```